# Why do dart tutorials always use `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `Map<String, Object?>`

Tags: flutter, dart

Even the [official tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) uses `Map<String, dynamic>`. I read somewhere that `dynamic` basically shuts down syntax checking and should be avoided. And in this case, JSON shouldn't contain any functions so it's safe to use `Map<String, Object?>` I believe. But why it's not widely used to represent JSON data?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map<String, Object?>` makes it harder to work with data represented with `Map` and extract it. When you do have many nested data, you will almost have type errors, which will require you to enforce casting types using `cast<T>()`, and `as`, and this can make the code have more boilerplate and mess which makes the code harder to read and a simple cast as example error will crash your whole code (app).

However, If you need more type safety, and to ensure the types are correct before moving to the next steps, it's your choice to use it.

Using `Map<String, dynamic>`, as the `dynamic` stands for, you can make the values be of any type and the `Map<String, dynamic>` will accept all of the types at that moment, then specifying the type of each one will be up to your use in your code, many Dart libraries such as `json_serializable`, `built_runner`.. requires simply to use `Map<String, dynamic>` and will make the serialization/deserialization os JSON easier and safer.